# in Table A has 10 rows and table B has 10 rows. The product of Table A and Table B would have 100 rows. ?

Tags: mysql

In mySQL Table A has 10 rows and table B has 10 rows. The product of Table A and Table B would have 100 rows?
I am stuck.

Comment: What is your mean "The product of Table A and Table B" ?

Answer (score 1):

If table1 has N rows and table2 has M rows, and you do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 A, table2 B
```

you get N X M rows.

Check if you like [Generating a Cartesian Product](http://web.utk.edu/sas/OnlineTutor/1.2/en/60477/m71/m71_3.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the product of two tables? If you join them loosely and select one column from each theb yes. But it makes no sense to do it.
You are probably not joining them properly.  If you could post your code it would help.